# vim - how to use environment variable in autocommand

Tags: vim

Win7x32 gvim 7.4

I want to call a batch file in response to the VimLeave event.
If my autocommand looks like this:

```
au VimLeave * !c:\users\Sauron\vimfiles\cleanSession.cmd
```

it works as expected.
I want to replace 'c:\users\Sauron' with '~' or '$HOME' or something similar, but have not gotten it to work.  I have tried:

```
au VimLeave * !$HOME\vimfiles\cleanSession.cmd  
au VimLeave * !%HOME%\vimfiles\cleanSession.cmd  
au VimLeave * !~\vimfiles\cleanSession.cmd
```

The '%' is expanded to the containing file's name.
$HOME doesn't get expanded.
I have tried quoting the path, and not.
What am I overlooking?
Thanks --

Answer (score 1):

```
exec 'au VimLeave * !' . fnameescape($HOME . '/vimfiles/cleanSession.cmd')
```

Welcome to the wonderful world of Vim command mode syntax. :)

Answer (score 1):

@lcd047's answer expands `$HOME` at autocommand *definition*; it's a bit more common to expand only at *invocation*. This also makes the command's syntax slightly more tolerable.

Additionally, `fnameescape()` is not the correct function; for `:!`, `shellescape()` (with the optional `{special}` argument) should be used:

```
au VimLeave * execute '!' . shellescape($HOME . '/vimfiles/cleanSession.cmd', 1)
```

Technically, escaping is only necessary if the path contains special characters, which is unlikely here, so you could also get away with:

```
au VimLeave * execute '!' . $HOME . '/vimfiles/cleanSession.cmd'
```